# how to use javaxt.io with SSJS in XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In an XPages application I would like to use the javaxt library to extract EXIF information from uploaded images.

My upload function runs in SSJS so my routine to check metadata looks as follwed (just a test)

```
try {
    importPackage(javaxt.io);
    var image = new javaxt.io.Image(tempFile);
    if (image != null) {
        print("image not null")

        var height = image.getHeight();
        if (height != null) {
            print(height);
        } else {
            print("no height")
        }

    }
} catch (e) {
    print("Upload.readMetaData: " + e.toString());
}
```

In the server console I get to see the following:

```
HTTP JVM: image not null
Upload.readMetaData: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I wonder what statement I should make instead of image.getHeight() ?

Comment: Please check if your temp file exists / is readable.

Comment: Move all your code to Java :-)

Comment: Check what type of object tempFile is. It should be a java.io.File

Comment: var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile() then I use it in my function e.g readMetaData( file:java.io.File ) so that it is

Comment: See if you can get to the whole stack trace in order to find out where the NPE is

Comment: @PatrickKwinten If you've found the root of the problem and an appropriate answer, you should add it as an answer, elaborate a bit in case anyone else comes across it, and mark it accepted.

Comment: sorry Eric, I am still on vacation so away from the pc (as much as possible)